# Formatting the date using Asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik, telerik-grid

I am using the below code to display the update date in my grid. But when I give like this I am getting the format of the date some like this

```
9/3/2012 6:14:51 PM

  columns.Bound(o => o.Datetime_Updated).Title("Update Date").Width(160);
```

But I need only hours and min in my code formate something like this

```
9.3.2012 6:14 PM
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
columns
  .Bound(o => o.Datetime_Updated)
  .Title("Update Date")
  .Width(160)
  .Format("{0:MM.dd.yyyy hh:mm tt}");
```

[Reference](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/grid/date-time-format-on-grid.aspx)

Comment: Just for completeness, the format string is composed using values from the chart here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx